# How to move a Project and API KEY from developer dashbord to the customer new account

Tags: google-maps

I've developed a desktop solution in `c#` using my account and api key.

Currently using

`add key="googleapikey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

and everything is fine.

Now it's time to release the project to the customer.

I'd like to know how to:

1. build a new account for api key for the customer
2. move or rebuild the api key of the desktop application to the new account
3. link all search costs and invoices to the customer.

Comment: I guess creating a new google for the client and generate a new API key will meet your requirements?

Comment: You cannot move an API key to another project as API keys are unique per project.

Comment: Cloud billing documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/